# What are the advantages of Visual Studio Team Server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My company is planning to move to TFS and I am working on the product analysis part. So far as a  developer I have used TFS in previous company but nothing much about the product. If someone could explain about pros & cons, how it will be helpful for testers, Architects like that, it will lbe helpful. I am also Googling on it.

Comment: I think it would be hard to give pros and cons without having another product to compare it to.  The current version (2010) is a very solid product, and what it does, it does well, but there are competitors that are stronger in some areas and weaker in others.  I think that as asked, this question is not truly answerable.  Earlier versions were good once you got them installed, but the install was probably the worst experience I've ever gone through with a Microsoft product.

Comment: Current envoirnment is VS2005 / VS2008 with VSS

Comment: OK, so all you've really got to compare it to is source control, correct?  VSS being Visual Source Safe?

Comment: Yes Visual Source Safe.. But they are looking to utilize it max like for testers,Architect..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going on your question and your comments above, just moving to ***anything*** other than Visual Source Safe will be an improvement. (see [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe.html))

TFS's source control alone is worth the cost of upgrading in my opinion.  However, the current version of TFS offers some very nice tools.  Source Control is a very small part if what it has to offer.

As I alluded to in the note above, the installation process for older versions of TFS are a nightmare.  If you do make the switch, I strongly recommend just going ahead and getting up to the 2010 version.  This means upgrading Visual Studio as well, but with the ability to edit .NET 2.0,3.0.3.5, and 4.0 in VS2010, that should not be an issue (unless cost is a factor).

Assuming that you have an MSDN Subscription for all of your tools, there really should be no question about whether or not to upgrade.  However, if you have bought the standalone versions, I'd recommend just getting the MSDN subscriptions. What you get for the money is more than worth it.

There's really just too much information to cover in this post, but I would recommend watching some of the videos here as the starting point for your research: http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=team+foundation+server+2010&qpvt=team+foundation+server+2010&FORM=VDRE#